# Does calling viewController without dismissing it create a second instance?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have been searching all over the web but I can't seem to find the answer to this.

Currently i am using presentViewController to start new ViewControllers, but on certain view controllers i do not dismiss it and call over it. I currently am not using any navigation controllers or anything like that.

I am just worried that if I call the same viewController again via presentViewController, that the same viewController would have 2 running instances.

Is it possible? Or does the iOS framework automatically reuse the idle viewController?

If so, how do i remove the idle view controllers?

Thank you! (I was holding back my question and tried to find it all over the web, so if you can point me in the right direction, it would be very helpful thanks!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS will not reuse your view controller, you can easily check it yourself by printing your view controller in viewDidLoad, you will notice first that viewDidLoad is called every time, and next that all objects have different addresses.

Unless you create thousand of them, or the navigation of your app doesn’t let you come back to an “idle” view controller, I would not say this is an issue though.
I don’t see any clean way to remove a view controller from the memory without calling “dismiss”. You could try to:
- “refresh” your view with new data.
- use something like [UIPageViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/) if the workflow of your app allows this kind of behaviour.
- rework the navigation so you can dismiss the view before calling another one

Good luck